# Auto refresh access tokens - Java Oauth client

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

Has anyone used java oauth2 client which auto refreshes the token using the refresh token by detecting the token has expired. some thing like

```
.getAccessToken(autoRefresh=true, ...)
```

So that when the library takes care of the refreshing part.

Or is this a valid use case at all ?

Pradeep.